# How can I install pure android and get rid of bloatware?

Tags: operating-system, bloatware

I am new here and already posted question on one of the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eyes-free/UJxnKBy0_pU),
I am curious to know few things regarding android OS.
I have Micromax Canvas HD 116 with Android 4.2.2 installed on it. What I hate is the unnecessary software offered by them, which is not occupying only space but also RAM and affecting speed of device. I just want to get rid of those bloatwares somehow.. I know if I follow some good rooting procedure, I can achieve it.. but is there any way, or official way so that I can manually re-install original pure android OS in my device.

I would be very much obliged if someone would provide some good resource about it.. and which is applicable to any device.

Thanks

Comment: If you dont want to root your device, you can disable the app from settings which stop them from running.

Comment: any other way..? just want to get rid of those nasty apps.. and if possible want to install pure android os

Comment: If you disable the app they will be no longer visible in your app drawer and they wont run on background which is pretty much what you needed I guess

Comment: @sameer ohh.. need to check

Comment: Go to settings->apps->all, click on the app you need to disable you will see a disable button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *official* way to install a "pure Android" ROM: the only official ROM is that provided by the manufacturer.

As sameer says in the comments, you can disable bloatware apps from the settings, with almost the same effect as uninstalling them.

If you want to start from a clean slate, you should look for an AOSP-based custom (unofficial) ROM. Although they aren't always as reliable as the manufacturer's ROM, because they're made by third-party volunteers, for the more popular devices with better manufacturer support they can be very reliable and even better tuned than the original ROM. Start your search at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/12442)

Comment: It's worth noting that the warning about removing/disabling system apps on manufacturer-altered UIs should be taken even more seriously than on "vanilla" Android.  Disabling a useless app can have unintended consequences on other, seemingly unrelated areas of the firmware.